# How to drag objects in axis(both x and y) but not diagonally in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

If the mouse is dragged in x axis then object should move in x axis
If the mouse is dragged in y axis then object should move in y axis
Object should not move diagonally

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var tempx:Number=0;
var tempy:Number=0;
var count:int=0;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,remov)
bl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,func)
function func  (f:MouseEvent)
{
    tempx=Math.abs(stage.mouseX);
    tempy=Math.abs(stage.mouseY);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mov)
}
function mov(h:MouseEvent)
{
    count+=1;
    if (count==4)
    {
    count=0;
    var Xval:Number=tempx-stage.mouseX;
    var Yval:Number=tempy-stage.mouseY;
    if(Math.abs(Xval)>Math.abs(Yval))
    {
    bl.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,bl.y,stage.stageWidth,0))
    trace ("X dragg")
    trace(Xval+""+""+Yval)
    }
    else
    {

        trace ("YY drag")
        trace(Xval+""+""+Yval)
        bl.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(bl.x,0,0,stage.stageHeight))
    }
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mov)
    }
}
function remov(y:MouseEvent)
{
    bl.stopDrag();
}
```

bl is the mc name
this works fine for me....Moving either in x or y axis alone....

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it. When your mouse is going to move diagonally, what will you do? An alternative could be something like that, where your object moves along the speediest axis:

```
var oldx:int;
var oldy:int;
var sx:int;
var sy:int;

function run(e:Event):void
{
    sx = Math.abs(mouseX - oldx);
    sy = Math.abs(mouseY - oldy);

    if (sx > sy) {
        c.x = mouseX;
    } else {
        c.y = mouseY;
    }

    oldx = mouseX;
    oldy = mouseY;
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, run);
```

**Other solution**

Another alternative consists in calculating the angle of your mouse:

```
var oldx:int;
var oldy:int;
var rd:Number;
var l1:Number = Math.PI / 4;
var l2:Number = 3 * Math.PI / 4;

function run2(e:Event):void
{
    rd = Math.atan2(mouseX - oldx, mouseY - oldy);

    if ((rd > l1 && rd < l2) || (rd < -l1 && rd > -l2)) {
        c.x = mouseX;
    } else {
        c.y = mouseY;
    }

    oldx = mouseX;
    oldy = mouseY;

}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, run2);
```